# css: show all floating text (variable font size) on the baseline

Tags: html, css

Any css tricks for getting text of any size to appear on the baseline for children inside one element that has float:left and another that has float:right?

Check out the jsfiddle link below to see what I'm talking about.  Notice how the word "One" has a larger font so it bumps all of it's siblings in the float:left down, but it does not influence the spans in the float:right div.

http://jsfiddle.net/QeRhU/

I'd like for them all to appear on the same baseline.  I'm hoping for a solution that still uses float:left; float:right; because I still want the liquid behavior that it gives when a user scales the page.

Comment: I also tried using line-height as well as a different setup for how I'm floating my elements but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/YvDzc/), it's not the clean solution, but rather a workaround that could get the job done if you don't find a cleaner css solution.

Comment: You are right that this is a workaround but it's the best solution I've seen so far.  I like that if I change the font size then this just works.